# What is the title of a story about a elevator through time and the smallest possible change

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, parallel-universe

Many years ago I read a story about a guy working for an organisation that would influence time-lines by traveling through time using a sort of elevator. The objective of the operators was to influence the time-line by making the smallest change possible.
Can anyone identify the name and author of the story?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think that's *[The End of Eternity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Eternity)* by Isaac Asimov.

Comment: I think you're right but the devices were called kettles from memory, however bizarre that sounds.

Answer (score -1):

There are two short stories that have this theme, "Blank!" and "The Instability". Both of them are huge.